# Permission Denied in Android How to solve it?

Tags: android, permissions, download

I trying this code but i always show the error Permission Denied.and i try code in below.

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hope.project"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

         <activity android:name="com.hope.project.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and i display in error:

```
 01-25 17:24:17.853: DEBUG/szipinf(12612): Initializing inflate state
01-25 17:24:17.853: DEBUG/szipinf(12612): Initializing zlib to inflate
01-25 17:24:19.201: DEBUG/dalvikvm(338): GC_EXPLICIT freed 17K, 5% free 6276K/6599K, paused 3ms+115ms
01-25 17:24:25.424: DEBUG/dalvikvm(206): GC_EXPLICIT freed 153K, 6% free 6730K/7111K, paused 4ms+94ms
01-25 17:25:11.912: DEBUG/SntpClient(71): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
01-25 17:25:24.961: VERBOSE/log(12612): onPageFinished: file:///android_asset/www/index.html#goToNode/2
01-25 17:25:27.276: VERBOSE/log(12612):  on ovverRide about:blank
01-25 17:25:44.464: VERBOSE/log(12612): onPageFinished: file:///android_asset/www/index.html#goToNode/328
01-25 17:26:25.692: VERBOSE/log(12612): onPageFinished: file:///android_asset/www/index.html#goToNode/10
01-25 17:26:25.901: DEBUG/dalvikvm(12612): GC_CONCURRENT freed 619K, 10% free 7242K/8007K, paused 4ms+3ms
01-25 17:26:33.711: VERBOSE/log(12612): login main url http://imprintingdesign.com/hiren_testing/TestHopeNew/testHope/pdf/TheMountain.mp4
01-25 17:26:33.781: VERBOSE/log(12612): login main url[0] http://imprintingdesign.com/hiren_testing/TestHopeNew/testHope/pdf/TheMountain.mp4
01-25 17:26:35.631: ERROR/Error:(12612): /mnt/sdcard/Downloads/TheMountain.mp4 (Permission denied)
```

and my downloaded class in below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView myWebView;
    TextView mDisplay;
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;

    String Message;
    String deviceId;
    String regId;
    IntentFilter gcmFilter;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    private final String PATH = "/sdcard/download/";
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);


        final JavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(
                this);
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface,
                "AndroidFunction");

        WebSettings settings = myWebView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);


         myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
               public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)  {                  

                            //handle stuff here 
                            //e.g. view.loadUrl(url);   
                   Log.v("log"," on ovverRide " + url);
                            return true;    
                        }

                        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                            //dismiss the indeterminate progress dialog
                            Log.v("log", "onPageFinished: " + url);
                            myWebView.setEnabled(false);

                        } 
                    });

        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    public class JavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }
        public void DownloadUrl(String url) {
            Log.v("log","login main url " + url);

            String file_url = url;
            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
            //new DownloadFromUrl(v,g);

            /*String url_new = "http://"+url;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url_new));
            startActivity(i);*/

        }
    }


    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread
         * Show Progress Bar Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
             Log.v("log","login main url[0] " + f_url[0]);
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                String name = f_url[0].substring(f_url[0].lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 1024 * 5);

                // Output stream to write file
                //OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Downloads/"
                + name);
                byte data[] = new byte[5 * 1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         * */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) 
        {
            // setting progress percentage
            //pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
       }

        /**
         * After completing background task
         * Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            //dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

            // Displaying downloaded image into image view
            // Reading image path from sdcard
            //String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile.jpg";
            // setting downloaded into image view
            //my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
        }

    }
```

Comment: where is the error ? writing the file ? did you try to save it somewhere else ? like at a more standard location ? (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() ?)

Comment: please add full stack trace of logs

Comment: i save the mp4 video in sdcard

Comment: does the Downloads directory exist?

Comment: Try using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` instead of `sdcard/downloads/` on your variable `PATH`.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Downloads/"+ name i used Vikalp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AndroidManifest.xml, Select the "Permissions" tab along the bottom of the editor (Manifest - Application - Permissions - Instrumentation - AndroidManifest.xml), then "Add..." a "Uses Permission" and select the desired permission from the dropdown on the right, or just copy paste in the necessary one (such as the "android.permission.INTERNET" permission you required).

For More information, Follow this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: I also add permission android.permission.INTERNET but error is give me below: /mnt/sdcard/Downloads/TheMountain.mp4 (Permission denied)

Comment: My problem solved .and i  define emulator memory size.and problem solved.thanks aakash reply my question.